# Why we use extends application

Tags: android-widget

```
MainActivity extends Application {
     ...
}
```

What is the use of writing `extends Application`?

Answer (score 0):

`Extends` means that it inherits from `Application`, therefore having all of the `Application` properties, methods, and so forth, but `extends` it with your specific functionality. In other words, `MainActivity` adds more to the base `Application`.